# Exposing API Endpoints in Frontend Application

Tags: reactjs, rest, github, jwt

I am building a frontend application using react and I am wondering whether it is risky to expose API endpoint URLs (ex: `https://myapi.com/v1/getitems`) on GitHub, assuming that the endpoint has several security measures that are not exposed such as `CORS` and `JWT Token Bearer Authentication`. I would assume not, since, if someone were to take the endpoint and send requests, they would need a token and be allowed to do so by CORS.

Is there any security risk in doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Don't add the base url of your api on github in plain view. Even though you might have `CORS` and `Authorization`, that doesn't stop a malicious actor  to keep spamming your back-end.

What you do is create a .env file in your root folder. You can use a library like `@beam-australia/react-env` and there are others as well.

You add in the .env file the values that are important for your environment and that are usually secrets, and you want them to not be visible in your code. You do it like so:

```
API_URL="https://myapi.com/v1"
```

And then you access this variable in your code with `env("API-URL")` ( in the `@beam-australia/react-env` case, but others libraries work the same). Keep in mind that you need to add `.env` in `.gitignore` so that the .env file is not pushed to github.

Regarding requests, you can make one like so:

```
fetch(`${env("API_URL}/getitems`)
```

This way your code will be stripped of the API's base url and if someone sees your code it will see only the endpoint, not the full url.

Comment: Never put secrets near your code. You can forget or mistype the gitignore file and publish it accidentally. Importing the env variable is a good practice though. Not sure if I should upvote this, I am puzzled.

Comment: @inf3rno Can't, hackers, go into dev tools and check the request my app is sending to my API? They can find the full URL there

Comment: @user19187727 Ohh I did not see it is react, I though you were talking about a server side client. If so, then you publish your secrets too along with your app except if you have a JWT service.

Comment: @inf3rno so basically using a .env file to store base API URL in react is fine?

Comment: @user19187727 Ok. Just to make some points clear. 1. You asked about publishing api urls to GitHub, not about deployed front-ends. For GitHub, .env is the way to do that. 2. The whole purpose for not publishing the api url in github is that if the repo is public, no one would be able to make calls to your api since they don't have the .env file. 3. For production front-ends, you can't hide in any significant way the api url, it will be visible in dev tools when you make requests. You should not hold some important secrets in front-end of course.But for api-url you don't have a choice

Comment: The only way your React app should work with secret keys in a safe way is with the help of a backend. However, your initial question wasn't about secret keys, rather it was about API url. So, the answer to that question is using `.env` file.

Comment: @user19187727 I edited my answer, maybe it makes sense this way.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing the code of the API is risky on its own. Somebody can find a vulnerability in it and instantly hack it. If you add the address of the API to the code you help this kind of attacks. They can get the address with some investigation; OSINT and social engineering too, but better to reduce the attack surface.

As of the secrets, they must never be near to the code, because you or another developer can accidentally publish it. It happened too many times with many developers, so better to take this seriously. If you want to keep the address in secret, then you must extract it from the code and put it in the configuration of the production environment which is imported from a totally different location than your code. Using environment variables like Alex suggested is a good idea for this. Nowadays it is common to use docker, which has a way to manage secrets, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/ Another aspect that the configuration belongs to the actual instance. In OOP terms you want to describe the injected properties of an object in its class or in a global variable, which is an antipattern.

As of client side REST clients like javascript applications running in the browser or Android/iOS apps, you must not publish your secrets along with the REST client, otherwise it is not a secret anymore. In that case you need a server side part for the REST client and for example sign and encrypt JWT there with a secret key. It is your decision whether this server side part of the REST client sends the HTTP request to the REST API and in that case you can hide the URI of the REST API or it just manages the JWT and the client side part of the REST client sends it. If the server side part of the REST client sends the HTTP request to the REST API, then you can even use traditional sessions with session cookies between the client side and the server side parts of the REST client, but you cannot use them between the server side part of the REST client and the REST API where the communication must be stateless. Though it does not make much sense to have a separate REST API if you don't have multiple different REST clients in this scenario e.g. browser clients for JS and JSless browsers, Android and iOS clients, fully automated clients running on servers, etc. So don't confuse the REST client - REST API relationship with the browser - HTTP server relationship, because they are not necessarily the same. Most of the REST clients run on servers, not in the browser.